# why or how did my path environment variable disappeared?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, environment-variables

an hour ago, after a normal restart, my PATH environment variable just disappeared.

It does **not** appear in the:

- not in System Properties/advanced/environment variables.
- nor under "User" and not under "System" variables
- not in the registry
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment

Fortunately, I have backup of my env vars, so the only question is

**WHY did it happen?**  (and not "how to repair it")

.

- I'm on Windows XP, sp3.
- before the incident I tried to install a new monitor, which didn't work
- I had other custom variables that I created manually for my own needs, and all these variables **remained** intact. Only the PATH variable vanished!
- all these variables (both PATH and my manually defined vars, where defined as System vars, not User vars
- since there was no PATH var, the default PATH pointed to C:\Windows\system32. this rules out security attack of that sort, I guess. (or just proves the opposite?!)

**edit** :  I ruled out gremlins, because it had happened before midnight && after 9PM

**edit2**:  I ran 2 registry cleaners just 3 days ago (reg-mechanic and regSeeker). the first took tons of time to run. It's not magic fairies but it's pretty close ;)

**edit3** - I did not touch or change my env variables lately, so it wasn't "by accident". besides, it happened twice already.

Comment: I would suspect a boot sector virus of some sort.

Comment: Magical fairies?  Act of god?  Gremlins?  Failed monitor install?  What have you already done to try and determine 'why'?

Comment: had i known what to rule out, i would've done and write about it. suggestions (based on your advice i ruled out gremlins.)

Comment: maybe you went to edit the path, highligted it, and accidentally clicked delete.. or you went to delete a variable near it, accidentally deleted path.. i've used xp for almost 10 years and not seen that. you could get a program to monitor the registry key there.

Comment: Did you install anything recently?  Ive seen some program installers wipe out the path variable before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was probably due to misuse of setx.exe inside a vbs script.

when using setx.exe, always surround variable contents with double-quotes,
e.g.

```
setx.exe varname "value of that var" -m
```

from vb variants:

```
cmd = "setx " + varName + " """ + Value + """ -m"
```

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea what caused it but I had the same problem so what I did was open cmd and type PATH then I copied what poped out on the screen and open system environment variables clicked new and created a variable named PATH and in value I pasted what I copied from cmd. Hope thid solves your problem